# MySQL FOR UPDATE exclusive access

Tags: mysql, concurrency

I have several servers hitting a common MySQL box and I need exclusive access to a table of scheduled jobs.
After some reading here and elsewhere I was led to believe SELECT...FOR UPDATE was what I wanted, but now we are (very rarely) seeing multiple servers pick up the same record.

Here's the PROC (minus the BEGIN/END stuff because it was playing hell with my formatting):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `PopScheduledJob`(OUT `JobId` varchar(36) )
    SELECT ScheduledJobId INTO JobId
    FROM scheduledjob
    WHERE 
    Status = 0
    AND NextRun < UTC_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY StartDate
    LIMIT 1     
    FOR UPDATE;

    UPDATE scheduledjob
    SET Status = 2
    WHERE ScheduledJobId = JobId;
```

So the intent here is that it should only pick up a job with Status=0, and it sets it to 1 immediately.
My hope was that this would prevent any other thread/process from accessing the same record, but now it seems that's not the case.

EDIT: forgot to mention, we have an InnoDB backing store

Comment: Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM tables?

Comment: If I'm reading [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) right you need to have autocommit disabled and wrap the whole thing in a transaction. Also, if you're using MyISAM you're going to wind up locking the entire table, whereas InnoDB will only lock the specified rows.

Comment: @Sammich yeah, that turned out to be it. they said I could use 'set autocommit = 0', or wrap it in a transaction. I opted for the latter and it worked! submit that as an answer instead of a comment and I'll send you some internet points